# Add-in rejected however the testing notes cover the issue the reviewer encountered

Tags: office-js, office-store

Our add-in was rejected due to the reviewer not reading/understanding our testing notes. It was rejected as 'not working' in Word 2013 however, the document is never saved even though we mention in our testing notes in multiple places you need to save the document for the add-in to work correctly.

> When testing whether the panel has updated the SharePoint metadata of the document being edited, **please make sure both the document is re-saved back to SharePoint** and that you’ve waited at least up to 60 seconds for SharePoint to update.  The parser (which is the SharePoint code to update the metadata from the document) takes up to 60 seconds to update metadata in the SharePoint library.

> If whilst editing a document in Word Application (not Online) and AutoSave is turned off, **you need to complete a Ctrl-S or File|Save for metadata changed to be reflected in SharePoint’s Library view.**
>
> **After updating the metadata in the add-in panel, a File|Save MUST be completed even though the panel flashes “Saved” on every metadata edit.**  **The flashing of “Saved” is the panel updating the document metadata, however, this does not mean that SharePoint is automatically updated, especially if AutoSave is turned off or using an older version of Word as old versions do not support AutoSave On feature.**
>
> Complete a File|Save, switch to SharePoint and refresh the library view to see the metadata changes reflected back in to SharePoint.

While we do mention the AutoSave feature - and that feature is not available in Word 2013 - I would expect a Microsoft Office Add-in Reviewer to have a basic understanding of what features are available in the Office product that they are validating an add-in against.

---

Questions:

**How can we ensure this does not happen in the future? We are trying to launch a product here and having to resubmit and wait another week each time is becoming a little tedious.**

**Is there a way to get in contact with Microsoft other than on StackOverflow for queries like these to allow us to work with the review team?**

Comment: "Please do not close this question. Microsoft Office Developers provides stackoverflow.com as the only way to get in contact with them regarding all developer issues regardless of whether they are programming questions." is a problem that has to be sorted out by microsoft...

Comment: @piet.t Understandable and I am waiting for their response. Please don't punish the users...

Comment: Please be aware that the validation team will not be able to discuss individual submission results on Stack Overflow.
As per our documentation, we cannot and do not provide customer support for individual submissions on StackOverflow. You can raise a Customer Support ticket here: https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution